# Achieve pure asynchronous behavior in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, curl, asynchronous

How can I achieve pure asynchronous behavior while using these:

JQuery/Javascript -> Ajax -> PHP -> CURL and then back to JQuery/Javascript.

Thanks.

Comment: Ajax stands for "Asynchronous Javascript and XML". What is really your question?

Comment: @Leo actually the question is that I am making 5 asynchronous ajax requests to PHP. The PHP makes api calls using cURL requests. Now the thing is that even if a single api call has returned I want to move forward and I am not sure how can I close the cURL handlers if they haven't returned any response. Here is full description - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34251766/close-any-open-curl-handlers-before-moving-forward